# Unable to make canvas size 1920x1080

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a monitor with resolution 1920x1080. I would like to have a full screen canvas that takes up this entire resolution.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="c"></canvas>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**index.css**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#c {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**index.js**

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('c');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.body.requestFullscreen();
    canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    console.log(canvas.width);
    console.log(canvas.height);
}, false);
```

When I click the screen I get a full screen canvas as expected but the logged output is

```
1920

969
```

Instead of 1920, 1080. How do I ensure that the canvas is taking up the full available resolution?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** It looks like the [Element.requestFullScreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) function is async which is why I probably can't set the canvas dimensions. The API says that it returns a promise  but I'm not sure how to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works on my side, try to not use % when possible, `vh` is more suited for your use case, example of CSS below.

```
html, body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/pen/poomVem

Comment: Your pen outputs 1920 x 497

Comment: Do a double click e.g. click once after it goes fullscreen, I'm using Firefox btw

Answer (score 0):

When you request fullscreen, it shows a popup first sometimes. Therefore, you may have to implement another event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
    // resize
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
    // resize
}, false);

document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
    // resize
}, false);

document.addEventListener("msfullscreenchange", function () {
   // resize
}, false);
```

Comment: Sure but there's no address bar and tab bar when it's in full screen. How do I set / query the full screen size of the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `document.body.clientWidth` and `document.body.clientHeight` will give you the *body* inner width and height.

To get the screen resolution, you must use `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height`.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.body.requestFullscreen().then(() => init());
}, false);


function init()
{
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

    console.log(canvas.height);
    console.log(canvas.width);
}
```

This is the solution. I'm using the Promise returned by `requestFullscreen` to trigger the canvas resize.